# Sum row values based on horizontal and vertical criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am looking to sum values in a row based on a horizontal month range and vertical name range.

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
**Name**     1       2      3       4       5             
Michael  $24,000 $36,000 $24,567 $45,000 $36,900    
Jerry    $27,000 $39,090 $55,567 $85,000 $39,900    
Sandra   $24,000 $36,000 $24,567 $45,000 $36,900    
Michelle $24,000 $36,000 $24,567 $45,000 $36,900
```

I want to be able to sum based on the month range.

For example, If I want to know what the value is for Sandra in months 3-5 ($24,567 + $45,000 + $36,900)

So everytime I play around with the range it should give me the sum of those values.

I tried an index match match function but I could only do it for a specific month not a range.

This was the formula I used :

```
=INDEX(Quota!$A$3:$P$29,MATCH('Summary by Rep'!A7,Quota!$A$3:$A$29,0),MATCH('Summary by Rep'!B4,Quota!$A$3:$P$3,0))
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use this array formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX(B2:F5,MATCH(I4,A2:A5,0),N(IF({1},ROW(INDIRECT(I2&":"&I3))))))
```

confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead Enter when exiting edit mode:

[image]

---

Or this that can be entered normally:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(B2:F5*(A2:A5=I4)*(B1:F1>=I2)*(B1:F1<=I3))
```

Answer (score 0):

Just building on Scott Craner's answers with another solution that does not involve array or array like formulas.

The INDEX function actually returns a cell address instead of a value.  Therefore you can use index once to define your starting cell of the range to sum, and then again to define the end cell of the range.

```
=SUM(INDEX():INDEX())
```

So based on the above formula you just need to figure out how your are going determine the start cell and then repeat the process for your end cell.  I did it with the MATCH function. and used the following formula:

```
=SUM(INDEX($B$2:$F$5,MATCH($H4,$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH($I4,$B$1:$F$1,0)):INDEX($B$2:$F$5,MATCH($H4,$A$2:$A$5,0),MATCH($J4,$B$1:$F$1,0)))
```

One small caveat that I have not tested, is that your name list and month list will may need to be sorted in ascending order.

[image: POC]